# Entity Framework from .NET 3.5 with SQL CE 4.0

Tags: .net, frameworks, sql-server-ce, entity

Is there a way to get the Entity Framework that ships with .NET 3.5 to work with SQL Compact 4.0?

I have a project that relies on .NET 3.5, and I can't move to .NET 4.0 yet, so Entity Framework 4 isn't an option. My existing code base works with .NET 3.5/EF 1/SQLCE 3.5 SP2, but on multi-threaded machines I get crashes now and then.

I'd like to move to SQL CE 4.0 to see if that resolves these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing additional research, the answer to this is no. SQL CE 4.0 will only work with EF 4.

Answer (score -1):

Try to make the changes to the edmx file and connection string I describe here:
http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/11/using-entity-framework-with-sql-server.html

Comment: This article appears to be talking about EF 4, not EF 1. I tried this techinque, and it fails with the error: "Data.TestDB.ssdl(2,91) : error 0004: Could not load System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll. Reinstall SQL Server Compact." I'm guessing this is because it's trying to load the .NET 4.0 version of that DLL, rather than the .NET 3.5 version.

Comment: The  System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll has a target framework of 4.0 and will not run under previous version, so it is not possible.